# Redirecting to www adds _/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

Im dealing with strange behavior using this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Howewer I dont thing the problem lies in this code. The redirecting is working good, but for example if I use this adrress `mysite.com/something`it redirect to `www.mysite.com/_/something`

Joomla htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule sitemap\.xml http://www.mojerc.cz/index.php?option=com_xmap&sitemap=1&view=xml [R]

## přesměrování na chybovou stránku 404
ErrorDocument 404 /obchod/poradce/404.html

########## Začátek - Joomla! jaderná SEF část.
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## Konec - Joomla! jaderná SEF část.

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
```

Have any of you ever encounter this strange thing?

Thanks for help.

Comment: do you have any other rules on your htaccess ?

Comment: nope, but this htacces is in root, maybe it is somehow rewrite by htacces in www directory? There is standard Joomla htaccess file.

Comment: Yes its possible, however if www is your root folder then your other htaccess would not work. FTP root folder and web root folder are not the same thing. Post your joomla htaccess.

Comment: I have to use this, because on my webhosting it redirection  wouldnt work if the command was in www folder, my root folder is folder with all subdomains and www as main domain. Updated the question with joomla htaccess

Comment: Put your `www` redirect rule after `RewriteBase /` and let me know how it goes, besides that I don't see any rule that would produce that `_` so perhaps your php could be doing it.

Comment: Still the same i'll have to look into php files, perhaps sef component is causing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for any `.htaccess` files in the directories that contain this directory as well. [According to the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#how):

> The configuration directives found in a .htaccess file are applied to
>   the directory in which the .htaccess file is found, and to all
>   subdirectories thereof. However, it is important to also remember that
>   there may have been .htaccess files in directories higher up.
>   Directives are applied in the order that they are found. Therefore, a
>   .htaccess file in a particular directory may override directives found
>   in .htaccess files found higher up in the directory tree. And those,
>   in turn, may have overridden directives found yet higher up, or in the
>   main server configuration file itself.

Also note, any directives in the server config file will also be processed as well. If you do not have access to the server config file (you're on shared hosting, or you're hosting with a company that manages that stuff for you) then you would need to contact the host to determine if the RewriteRules exist in that file.

Additionally remember that PHP and other dynamic languages can also do `header()` commands similar to Apache and cause the page to redirect as well (but they would have to be in one of the PHP files).

You can use a plug-in in a browser like Firefox's *Live HTTP Headers* to view the headers when you load the page to see where the redirects are happening. (Make sure you're not running a lot of tabs at once though.)

**Update**
Something else occurred to me. If you *had* a rule before that was a 301 redirect that included the `_/` then it's likely cached in your browser if you've removed that rule already. In this code you've posted I don't see any rules that would cause the behavior you're experiencing. Since you're running Joomla, it may be in the Joomla config (possibly the default directory for the install).

Comment: Thanks, all other .htaccess are clean, i'll try to look for header in php files.

Comment: Im quite sure that you named all the posibilities in that matter and thanks for headers plugin.